# Export HTML elements to Excel in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, excel, c#-4.0

I have a requirment is to export data from DB table to Excel. I'm using MVC project where from View the user click a button to call a controller action to perform the export opertaion. The DB proc returns rows where couple of columns contains HTML data like

> ```
> <ul><li>Name1</li><li>Name2</li></ul>
> ```

and this should be shown in Excel cell as below

- Name1
- Name2

How can i do this ? any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Text styling is very limited in Excel and you cannot create bulleted lists directly. You will have to insert bullet characters manually, set the indentations, etc.

Comment: Hi Martin,thanks for response. Are you sure there is no way of styling in Excel ? my prob is there might be more HTML tags in the data, so it might be tough to do manually. Any other go ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make a *document*, not a *spreadsheet*. Are you sure you want Excel and not Word here?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of doing something in Excel via C# that cannot be done directly from the interface. And there is no way of setting paragraph properties in Excel, you can only style fonts. You can include line breaks, but there is for example no way of having different leading.

Comment: Hi lc, im trying to make a preadsheet not word. The formating of the data should be done in the Excel cell(s)

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks. Is there any example code which i can refer ?

Answer (score 0):

To recap the comments:

- In general it's not possible to apply any styling via code (VBA or C#) that cannot be applied through the Excel interface.
- Styling possibilities in Excel are quire limited, you can set font properties (size, weight, font, etc) by character, but 'paragraph' formatting can only be set per cell if at all.
- Things that can be set per cell are alignment and indent (and text wrapping)

In order to simulate the bullet list, you could use VBA code like this:

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = Chr(149) & " foo" & vbCrLf & Chr(149) & " bar"
Cells(1, 1).IndentLevel = 2
```

C# code would be very similar.

But this is as good as it gets, doing anything more complicated in a single cell is unfortunately not possible. If you have to use Excel, I suggest you have just single paragraph per cell.